# How to manipulate the geometry of a shapefile polygon using sf in R

Tags: r, r-sf

I have two shapefile polygons, one with a defined CRS (shapefile A) and another with an undefined CRS (shapefile B). I have lat/long coordinates with geometries similar to that of shapefile A. However, I want to count these points in the polygons of shapefile B. I realize that simply setting the CRS in shapefile B to that of shapefile A does not solve the problem as the geometries are different.

How do I go about modifying the geometry of shapefile B so that it matches with shapefile A? The closest help I found was to apply an affine transformation on the polygons, but I'm not sure how to go about doing so, if that is the correct method.

Here are some descriptions of the two shapefiles (note the bbox and CRS fields in particular):

**Shapefile A**

```
Simple feature collection with 61 features and 29 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -61.93033 ymin: 10.04404 xmax: -60.90916 ymax: 10.84451
geographic CRS: WGS 84
```

**Shapefile B**

```
Simple feature collection with 534 features and 13 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 617063.2 ymin: 1110279 xmax: 728431.5 ymax: 1199347
CRS:            NA
```

I imagine that I would need to multiply the geometries of shapefile B by -10^-4 for the x coordinates and 10^-5 for the y coordinates but I'm not sure if the negative will reflect the shapefile as well. If so, is it still possible to apply another viable transformation?

Comment: I'm not an expert in `sf`, but it would seem that you need to figure out the CRS of shapefile B, set it, and use [`sf::st_transform`](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_transform.html).

Comment: yeah the best solution is to find out what CRS shapefile B is in, set it using `sf::st_crs()`, then transform it to 4326 using `sf::st_transform()`

Comment: Hmm unfortunately I'm not exactly sure how to go about finding out what CRS shapefile B is in. If it helps, both shapefiles represent the island of Trinidad. Shapefile B has communities as polygons while shapefile A has police station districts as polygons. I received the communities shapefile from the Central Statistics Office. Should I enquire about the crs from them or can I get it through some other means?

Comment: I should also mention that my main objective is to count the number of crime occurrences in each community. I have these crimes as points which can be easily assigned to the wgs 84 crs and counted in the polygons of shapefile A. However, I’m getting an error with invalid latitude and longitude, and zero counts when I attempt to count the points in shapefile B.

Comment: might want to try setting the crs as one of these & see if one works: https://epsg.io/?q=Trinidad+and+Tobago

Comment: Update: setting the crs of shapefile B to the epsg 2067 datum and then transforming to 4326 worked.